# Designing a derived type with array components

Tags: arrays, fortran, structure, dynamictype, allocatable-array

I have struggled to find any concrete information where designing a derived type is concerned. I think the best way to discuss this is through a couple of options. I have made up some sections of code with different applications of the derived type. I would prefer to use dynamic arrays for `nparts`, `index`, and `refs`. I have omitted sections of code that actually uses the structure (there isn't any because I made it up), but an examples are shown and in a routine I intend to use all of the values in the structure at least once.

**Option A:** Use static arrays in the derived type. Downside is that I would have to guess the array size at compile time.

```
! Known before compile time.
nboxes = 5000
max_parts = 2000
packs = 10

Type Boxes
   Sequence
   Integer :: location, date
   Integer, Dimension(0:packs) :: nparts
   Integer, Dimension(max_parts,packs) :: index
   Real(Kind=8), Dimension(packs,packs) :: refs
End Type Boxes

type(boxes), dimension(:), allocatable :: assembly
allocate(assembly(nboxes))

! Perform some operations on assembly...
do i = 1,nboxes
   do j = 1,packs
      do k = j,packs
         example = assembly(i)%nparts(k) - assembly(i)%nparts(j)
         .
         .
         do m = 1,max_parts
            example = assembly(i)%index(m,j) + assembly(i)%refs(k,j) * assembly(i)%nparts(j)
            .
            .
         end do
      end do
   end do
end do
```

**Option B:** Use dynamic arrays in the derived type.

```
! Defined during execution. Much better.
nboxes = 5000
max_parts = 2000
packs = 10

Type Boxes
   Sequence
   Integer :: location, date
   Integer, Dimension(:), Allocatable :: nparts
   Integer, Dimension(:,:), Allocatable :: index
   Real(Kind=8), Dimension(:,:), Allocatable :: refs
End Type Boxes

type(boxes), dimension(:), allocatable :: assembly
allocate(assembly(nboxes))
do i = 1,nboxes
   allocate(assembly(i)%nparts(0:packs))
   allocate(assembly(i)%index(max_parts,packs))
   allocate(assembly(i)%refs(packs,packs))
end do

! Perform some operations on assembly...
do i = 1,nboxes
   do j = 1,packs
      do k = j,packs
         example = assembly(i)%nparts(k) - assembly(i)%nparts(j)
         .
         .
         do m = 1,max_parts
            example = assembly(i)%index(m,j) + assembly(i)%refs(k,j) * assembly(i)%nparts(j)
            .
            .
         end do
      end do
   end do
end do
```

**Option C:** Minimize the number of dynamic arrays used in the derived type and force `assembly` to become the array. Notice though that in this version, we have a bunch of unused memory. For example, `nparts` and `index` need memory `packs`-times since `assembly(packs,packs,nboxes)`.

```
! Defined during execution. Much better.
nboxes = 5000
max_parts = 2000
packs = 10

Type Boxes
   Sequence
   Integer :: location, date, nparts, index
   Real(Kind=8) :: refs
   Integer, Dimension(:), Allocatable :: index
End Type Boxes

type(boxes), dimension(:,:,:), allocatable :: assembly
allocate(assembly(packs,packs,nboxes))
do i = 1,nboxes
   do j = 1,packs
      do k = 1,packs
         allocate(assembly(k,j,i)%index(max_parts))
      end do
   end do
end do

! Perform some operations on assembly...
do i = 1,nboxes
   do j = 1,packs
      do k = j,packs
         example = assembly(k,j,i)%nparts - assembly(k,j,i)%nparts
         .
         do m = 1,max_parts
            example = assembly(k,j,i)%index(m) + assembly(k,j,i)%refs * assembly(k,j,i)%nparts
            .
            .
         end do
      end do
   end do
end do
```

**Option D:** Another permutation of Option C.

Questions:

1. Which version is the correct/expected method of designing a derived type for the `do` loop example shown? Which version is most optimized considering that I would like dynamic array capabilities?
2. Maybe related to above. How is the memory allocated and accessed? Is the use of `SEQUENCE` even worthwhile? I think allocated arrays wouldn't show up in sequence anyways. Wouldn't this point to Option C being the best since each section of `assembly` is smaller?
3. Should I maybe split this derived type into multiple derived types or get rid of it altogether and just stick to variables? I will be using this derived type over multiple routines and would put it in a module.

Comment: Does your compiler support parameterized derived types?

Comment: It does, although I am unfamiliar with the concept and application. So my mind doesn't support it yet. :)

Comment: `kind=8` is really ugly, avoid magic constants! It does not mean 8 bytes! Atleast not in all compilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You want the fastest varying index to be your innermost loop. The fastest varying index is the first in a multi-dimensional array. Thus, option B comes close to this goal. Though you might want to change the ordering of the dimensions in refs.
2. The memory layout for a two-dimensional array of shape (m,n), which is accessed by the indices (i,j) is given by the following ordering: `k = i+m*(j-1)`, where `k` denotes the one-dimensional index in memory. The derived data-type would contain a reference to the allocated memory, and the actual memory of the contained allocatables may be scattered across memory, but each allocatable array is contiguous in itself. So, in your option B the `assembly` would be a contiguous array containing references to allocatable arrays. Each of `nparts`, `index` and `refs` would be contiguous arrays in themselves but the may be located at arbitrary places with no specific relation within one assembly element or across different assembly elements. Use of `SEQUENCE` does not make any sense here, it forces the compiler to put the elements of the derived data type into the memory in the order, that you state and will prohibit it to re-arrange the data-type components as it sees fit, which may limit the performance. I doubt, it would have large effects in your example, but when it is not needed you should leave it.
3. No, option B looks perfectly reasonable, in my opinion (except for the `sequence`).

Comment: 1. Oops, oversight on my part. I have edited the code in the question so that this is correct. 2. Does `SEQUENCE` in Option A help in terms of optimization? I was under the impression that having that information located adjacent in memory would improve the computational speed within the loops. Would it be even better to use a derived type where the memory is contiguous for each loop and allocatable? For example, a variation on Option C where `index` is no longer an array in the derived type.

Comment: @Higgy which information are you referring to with respect to `SEQUENCE`? From a performance point of view it mostly is a bad idea to put it into derived data-types. As I said, it forces the compiler to use the ordering you impose. Thus, it has less options for optimizations. You want to have arrays, that's where Fortran shines, and I believe option B gives you the best variant. Performance-wise option A would probably be even better, but you said you'd like to use dynamic memory allocation. Variations of C are worse than A and B, in my opinion.

Comment: Very well. That clears it up for me. Is there ever a reason where `SEQUENCE` would be beneficial?

Comment: @Higgy From http://www.fortran.com/fortran_storenew/Html/Info/books/key10.pdf: "The SEQUENCE statement is used: (a) to allow objects of this type to be storage associated, or (b) to allow actual and dummy arguments to have the same type without use or host association". About argument association, maybe have a look at: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/03/31/doctor-fortran-in-ive-come-here-for-an-argument

Comment: Assuming you are using ifort then REAL(KIND=8) is OK and means 8 bytes, however I do not see intel-fortran in the tags. I would probably use an array alignment in the compiler switches, or in ifort as a !DIR$ ATTRIBUTES ALIGN : 64:: assembly.